# ApplicationRoute does not work on cli app

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have just installed the latest version of ember-cli (0.0.46) and generated a new app `ember new myapp`.
Without changing anything else I have added the application route as below

```
#app/routes/application.js
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
   return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});
```

in order to display the three colors in a list in the template. 
However when I start the server (`ember server`) I get

```
routes/application.js: line 1, col 1, 'App' is not defined.
routes/application.js: line 1, col 24, 'Ember' is not defined.

2 errors
```

Am I missing anything here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ember-CLI` uses ES6 modules as noted in the docs http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-modules.

So using the global `App` will not work.Instead you need to do something like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
   return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});
```

Also the cli has support for generating blueprints, so you can do something like

```
ember generate route route-name
```

and it will create the necessary files for you. Check out http://www.ember-cli.com/#generators-and-blueprints